# Differential equation $a_0g+a_1g'+a_2g''+\cdots+a_ng^{(n)}=f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Any idea about this problem:

If $f:\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}($open simply connected$)\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function then the differential equation $$a_0g+a_1g'+a_2g''+\cdots+a_ng^{(n)}=f$$ admits a holomorphic solution $g:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nice result. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b\in \mathbb{C}$. As $\Omega$ is simply connected, there exists an holomorphic $F$ such that  $F^{\prime}(z)=f(z)\exp(-bz)$. The function $g(z)=F(z)\exp(bz)$ satisfy $g^{\prime}(z)-bg(z)=f(z)$ and is holomorphic on $\Omega$. Then use induction on $n$.